# OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin 6.6.0 creates Build Failure in Maven Clean Install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mojo, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have to produce a OpenAPI Specification from an existing REST based project. One thing i did was to include the springdoc-openapi and swagger-webmvc-ui dependency and it was creating the desired spec on localhost:8080/api-doc. Now, I want to do this via OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin 6.6.0 such that when I run mvn clean install, it will produce the spec in yaml/json format in the directory i specify in the generator plugin. But, this is causing build failure with the following error related to MOJOs. I guess I am not doing anything wrong but it will be helpful if you mention the required steps to generte the yaml/json file in resources directory.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--------< [0;36morg.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc[0;1m >--------[m
[INFO] [1mBuilding springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc 3.1.6-SNAPSHOT[m
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[INFO] 
[INFO] [1m--- [0;32mopenapi-generator:6.0.0:generate[m [1m(default)[m @ [36mspringdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc[0;1m ---[m
[WARNING] Exception while reading:
io.swagger.v3.parser.exception.ReadContentException: Unable to read location `/home/adminuser622/Work/springdoc-openapi-demos-master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/resources/api.yaml`
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContentFromLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:274)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:89)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext(CodegenConfigurator.java:541)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:599)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:759)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find /home/adminuser622/Work/springdoc-openapi-demos-master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/resources/api.yaml on the classpath
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath(ClasspathHelper.java:31)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readContentFromLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:265)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] failed to read resource listing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find /home/adminuser622/Work/springdoc-openapi-demos-master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/resources/api.yaml on the classpath
    at io.swagger.parser.util.ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath(ClasspathHelper.java:31)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:206)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:122)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readWithInfo(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:93)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.readWithInfo(SwaggerParser.java:44)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation(SwaggerConverter.java:90)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toContext(CodegenConfigurator.java:541)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:599)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:759)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] Generating with dryRun=false
[INFO] Output directory (/home/adminuser622/Work/springdoc-openapi-demos-master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/target/generated-sources/openapi) does not exist, or is inaccessible. No file (.openapi-generator-ignore) will be evaluated.
[WARNING] /home/adminuser622/Work/springdoc-openapi-demos-master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/resources/api.yaml [0:0]: unexpected error in Open-API generation
java.lang.RuntimeException: Issues with the OpenAPI input. Possible causes: invalid/missing spec, malformed JSON/YAML files, etc.
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:850)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:781)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Issues with the OpenAPI input. Possible causes: invalid/missing spec, malformed JSON/YAML files, etc.
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:850)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute(CodeGenMojo.java:781)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:195)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[INFO] Total time:  3.870 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-30T14:56:47+05:30
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.0.0:generate[m [1m(default)[m on project [36mspringdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc[m: [1;31mCode generation failed. See above for the full exception.[m -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Also, there is a underline showing error in , see the picture below?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m26jQ.png)

I want to generate OpenAPI spec in yaml/json format not on localhost:8080/api-docs but in the resources directory automatically during maven clean install.

Comment: I think you need the [springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin](https://springdoc.org/plugins.html), not the openapi-generator plugin. OpenAPI Generator is used for the opposite thing - generate code from an OpenAPI spec.

Comment: The problem is related to this: `Unable to read location `/home/adm`...